# Why I am getting errors from TableGen-generated *.inc files (LLVM)?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm

I am trying to write an LLVM backend, when I am trying to build it, I get the following error message:

```
AbcGenRegisterInfo.inc: In static member function 'static const llvm::AbcFrameLowering* llvm::AbcGenRegisterInfo::getFrameLowering(const llvm::MachineFunction&)':
AbcGenRegisterInfo.inc:322:43: error: invalid static_cast from type 'const llvm::TargetFrameLowering*' to type 'const llvm::AbcFrameLowering*'
    MF.getSubtarget().getFrameLowering());
    ^
```

Here is my `AbcRegisterInfo.td` (*I copied it from [here](https://github.com/Bigcheese/llvm/blob/aiobj/lib/Target/AIObj/AIObj.td)*):

```
class AbcReg<string n> : Register<n> {
    let namespace = "Abc";
}

def DUMMY_REG : AbcReg<"R0">;

def RegI64 : RegisterClass<"Abc", [i64], 64, (add DUMMY_REG)>;
```

I also overrided `AbcSubtarget::getFrameLowering()` method:

```
class AbcSubTarget : public AbcGenSubtargetInfo {
    AbcFrameLowering *frameLowering;

    // more fields and methods

    const AbcFrameLowering *getFrameLowering() const override {
        return frameLowering;
    }
};
```

but the error message did not change.

I don't understand what to do - I can't just edit `AbcGenRegisterInfo.inc`, because it will be re-generated every time I will build LLVM, and I don't understand what's wrong in my TableGen files.

---

I also tried to remove `AbcGenRegisterInfo.inc` file from my build directory before compiling, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does AbcFrameLowering inherit from TargetFrameLowering?  It looks like the static cast is complaining because the types are unrelated.

Also make sure the header with the definition of AbcFrameLowering is included before the .inc file is included otherwise the static cast will fail as well.

Comment: Thanks, your second advise helped - `AbcFrameLowering.h` wasn't included in the right place. I included it and... got 8 new errors, but there wasn't `static_cast` error :D

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact error, and while I cannot answer your question in full, I believe I can address one part of the issue. You said

I also tried to remove AbcGenRegisterInfo.inc file from my build directory before compiling, but it had no effect.

Unless you mean that AbcGenRegisterInfo.inc was regenerated (and therefore deleting it had no effect), the fact that its absence has no effect should be due to the fact that TableGen has the .inc.tmp file to rely on as a backup. I noticed that when I make with VERBOSE=1, there is a statement that suggests tablegen uses the .tmp files in this way.

Again, not a specific answer to your main question, but just to hopefully help address that issue when trying to debug.

Comment: I mean that it was regenerated. But I found this .tmp file and deleted both .inc and .inc.tmp files, and again no effect. I don't really think that the problem is that TableGen backups files -- the problem must be somewhere in my code